# Cannot accept invitation to VSTS - Select Country/Region is empty

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I've invited user from my AAD to VSTS. He recieved email and logged in. In the form "We need more details" you ask for Name, email  (`We'll reach you at:`) and country/region (`From:`).

However, the `From:` dropdown is empty and I'm, not able to select any country/region

In browser's developer tools I see some failed reqeust requesting user profile.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, tried Incognito and several browsers.  Is it just a waiting game now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log on to azure portal and set Usage Location for that user (Profile).

Comment: I've done it. The user is still not able to fill the form

Comment: **After couple of hours, the form just started to work.** @starain-MSFT : your help here on stackoverflow is gorgeous. `@ Microsoft`: shame on you and quality of your products!!! wake up and start focusing on quality! And hire testers!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem last week.

**My resolution was to try a different browser (in my case chrome) and use "incognito"-mode.**

Comment: Neither incognito window, not different browser does not help