# Azure AD Sync with Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I've successfully connected my Azure DevOps organization with my Azure AD Tenant. Authentication works ok (only users from my tenant can log in)  but I can't see any groups from my Azure AD on Azure DevOps level (it is like 5 days after I've done the connection) so my question is how to fore sync between Azure Ad and Azure DevOps? My goal is to have one group on Azure AD (where I would add people responsible for dev-ops stuff) and add this group to Azure DevOps.

I will be very grateful for any help or pointers on how to solve this.

Comment: does the group show up in Azure AD and not in Azure Devops or does it not show up anywhere?

Comment: It is shown on Azure AD (I even assigned few users to it) but it does not aper on Azure DevOps

Comment: it might be not supported, is it a security group?

Comment: yes exactly it is security group

Comment: base on that it should be supported https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/manage-azure-active-directory-groups?view=azure-devops

Comment: it doesnt really say that synced groups are supported. logically they should but logic doesnt always apply...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds very familiar to my issue I was having, which I posted a similar answer to on [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55803429/1196415).

Essentially you cannot see/search Azure AD users or groups as a Guest user - are you a Guest user in this Azure AD?

If you are a guest user you will need to convert yourself to a Member rather than Guest.

My solution was to

- Download the AzureAD powershell module

  - `Install-Module AzureAD`
- Connect to my AzureAD instance

  - `Connect-AzureAD -TenantId [your tenant id]`
- Update the user

  - `Set-AzureADUser -ObjectId [User object id] -UserType Member`

Once I logged out and in again (clearing my cookies) - tadaa! All my Azure AD groups/users were visible to me in the add screens of my DevOps organization.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion to fore sync between Azure Ad and Azure DevOps you can create group in azure AD and then add that to the built in groups which are already there in the AD. The azure devops permissions comes in sync that way. "Azure AD group members inherit permissions from the Azure DevOps group, so you don't have to manage group members one at a time."

Comment: But if I want to use my own custom group to manage permission on a single project level this will not work

Comment: It will work if you add the custom group within the built in group

Answer (score 0):

As of March-2024, there is [direct way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/connect-organization-to-azure-ad?view=azure-devops) to do this:

1. On Azure DevOps as Admin, Go to **Organisation Settings** > **General** > **Microsoft Entra**.
2. Click on **Connect Directory** Button
3. Select the Tenant and click **connect**.

[image]

[image]

**Warning**: Please ensure that you are member on tenant you connect to else might lose acess to the Azure Organisation.